# SFINAE в определении возвращаемого типа шаблонной функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++14

```
auto foo(...) {
}

template<typename T>
auto foo(T arg) {
    return arg->sfinae;
}

template<typename T>
auto bar(T arg) -> decltype(foo(arg)) {
}

int main() {
    bar(42);
}
```

Почему [компилятор выдаёт сообщение об ошибке](https://godbolt.org/z/leIHYz), а не срабатывает SFINAE?

> error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer

Comment: А что такое sfinae? Где этот объект объявлен?

Comment: И что вы собираетесь получить от 42->sfinae?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `sfinae` нигде не объявлен, а назван так, чтобы подчеркнуть, что в данном месте подразумевается substitution failure, т.е. чтобы шаблонный кандидат не подходил в overload resolution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правило SFIANE относится только к декларации функции (типам аргументов и результату). Определение тела функции, должно компилироваться и его ошибка компиляции - обычная ошибка компиляции.

Декларация `auto foo(T arg)` подходит для любого типа, включая int, но при компиляции тела функции - выдает ошибку.

Исправить просто:

```
void foo(...) {
}

template<typename T>
auto foo(T arg) -> decltype(arg->sfinae) {
    return arg->sfinae;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`S` в `SFINAE` обозначает `Substitution`, то бишь подстановку (выведенного) шаблонного параметра, которая определяется в стандарте как

> **17.9.2 Template argument deduction [temp.deduct]**
>   7 The substitution occurs in all types and expressions that are used in the function type and in template parameter declarations.

Соответственно в данном случае подстановка происходит успешно, а вот ошибка в теле функции уже становится обычной ошибкой, а не приводит к выкидыванию функции из перечня перегрузок.